# Почему плавающий элемент вытесняет строчный элемент выше?

Tags: html, css

Не понимаю почему элемент с `float:left` ниже чем `span`, но он все равно его вытесняет, подымаясь вверх.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.float {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <span>Текст</span>
  <div class="float"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' не понимаю почему так.

Comment: @Sevastopol' хочу именно понять почему так происходит. Я нигде не нашел об этом информацию.

Comment: @Sevastopol' если бы текст был снизу, то это было бы логично (текст бы обтекал элемент с float). Но текст сверху, поэтому это странно.

Comment: @Sevastopol' я хочу именно объяснения, из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: Он не ниже. Верх у него там же, где и у текста.

Comment: @Alexey Ten в html он ниже, чем span

Comment: Ну и что? Это совершенно неважно. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position п.8. Флоат должен быть как можно выше (с учётом 7 предыдущих пунктов)

Comment: @Alexey Ten скажите пожалуйста где конкретно там это написано?

Comment: Эм? Вот прямо по ссылке алгоритм размещения флоатов из 9 пунктов

Comment: @ Alexey Ten  если бы умел читать спецификацию, то вряд ли задавал бы вопросы здесь. Придется переводить. Спасибо что показали где написано, так как в русском сегменте я ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно `Float` определяет, по какой стороне будет выравниваться элемент. При этом остальные соседние элементы будут обтекать его с других сторон.

Сначала плавающие элементы выстраиваются в нормальном потоке (в вашем случае это элемент `.float`), а затем уже образуется новый поток (в вашем случае это строчный элемент `span`), и они сдвигаются либо вправо, либо влево (в зависимости от выбранного значения) в родительском контейнере.

> Нормальный поток — это порядок вывода элементов на страницу. В обычном виде все блоки выводятся в том порядке, в котором они записаны внутри HTML документа. Ваш нормальный поток нарушает элемент `.float`, после чего уже образуется новый поток, который начинается со строчного элемента `span`.

Плавающие элементы, их называют еще "поплавками", прижимаются к границам своих контейнеров, но не дальше, и не могут подняться выше верхнего края своего же родительского контейнера (в вашем случае это блок `.container`).

Как рекомендация для вас:

> плавающий элемент `.float` должен быть помещен как можно выше.

Но если же вы планируете его разместить ниже строчного элемента `span`, то элементу `span` необходимо применить свойство `display: block`, пример ниже.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.float {
  position: relative;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Текст</span>
  <div class="float"></div>
</div>
```